# Image names appear in google description of my website

Tags: html, robots.txt, google-search, google-search-appliance

As the question says I would like to now how to remove names and sections from the description of google search. As per now my this a fragment of the description that google provides from my website when I google it:

`squirrel_logo. text_claim. Sign up with .edu m.....`

I want to remove the squirrel_logo. and text_claim for example. I've heard about the robots.txt file and I have one as follows

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /media/
Disallow: /static_medias/
```

It's the robots.txt file the way to solve this? then why it's not working? (needs time to update?)

A part from that I would like to exclude the "register page" but I don't know how to do it without excluding the whole website. I mean I want to exclude the direction mydomain.com (because it only has sign up info) but not mydomain.com/home.

Comment: Consider posting this question [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure these descriptions aren't part of the image's alternate text or title text attributes? For example you might find you have

```
<img src='../path/images/sqrl_logo.jpg' alt='squirrel_logo' />
```

Instead you should just have:

```
<img src='../path/images/sqrl_logo.jpg' alt='' />
```

Although alternate text helps screen-readers and people who aren't rendering images they don't need to know about graphics that simply 'adorn' the design of the page. If it's a picture of a building the article is about, you might consider a description in the "alt" text, however screen readers don't want to waste their time saying "td image left with stripes" (for example).

Comment: You are correct the text showing up it's the alt field. I'll consider removing it. About shutting down "mydomain.com" but not "mydomain.com/homepage" any idea?

Comment: There's probably not a perfect answer to this, and the nearest I found is here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31553/in-robots-txt-how-do-i-disallow-all-pages-except-for-the-index-page The only other thing I could suggest is changing the location (somehow) of the sign-up info.